# numerical order but longest digit first

Tags: java, string, sorting

Say I have an array of Strings like:

```
1000
2000
100
200
20
10
```

how can I order them so that the first digits are ordered numerically, yet it's the longest first?

e.g.

```
1000
100
10
2000
200
20
```

(This may be trivial but I just can't think of anything).

Comment: What happens if I add 210 and 220 to your list? where should those go?

Comment: It would follow as 2000 > 220 > 210 , as they would be the next largest numbers with 2 as the first digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement a comparator which first sorts on the first digit, and then sorts in reverse on the length.

In Java 8+:

```
Comparator<String> yourComparator =
    Comparator.comparing((String s) -> s.charAt(0))
        .thenComparing(
            Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());
```

If you're still stuck in the dark ages, you can implement this explicitly:

```
Comparator<String> yeOldeComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override public int compare(String a, String b) {
    int cmpFirst = Integer.compare(a.charAt(0), b.charAt(0));
    if (cmpFirst != 0) return cmpFirst;

    return Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length());
  }
};
```

Note that neither of these handle empty (or null) strings.

---

In response to [Patrick Parker's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7098259/patrick-parker) comment, you might want to add further sorting to ensure a stable order if the inputs are of the same length and begin with the same character.

In the Java 8 case:

```
// ... As above, but add this before the semicolon:
.thenComparing(naturalOrder());
```

In the pre-Java 8 case:

```
// Replace return Integer.compare with:
int cmpLength = Integer.compare(b.length(), a.length());
if (cmpLength != 0) return cmpLength;

return a.compareTo(b);
```

Comment: Perfect solution! I had completely forgotten to have 2 checks inside a comparator